# Display custom contact dashboard only to certain Contact subtypes

Tags: smarty

Drupal 7.78
Civi 5.28.2

I am setting up a custom contact dashboard following [Demerit's answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31924/displaying-custom-contact-fields-in-contact-dashboard) using UserDashBoard.extra.tpl and smarty's crmAPI.

But I only want it to be for contact sub-type = Student. How would I write an IF statement for that?

Here is my best guess but it does not work.

```
    {crmAPI var='result' entity='Contact' action='get' id=$contactId sequential=0}
{foreach from=$result.values item=contact}
  {if $contact.contact_sub_type = 'Student'}

<table class="dashboard-custom"><tr><td><strong>Student Demographics</strong></td></tr>
{crmAPI entity='Contact' action='get' var='result' id=$contactId return="birth_date,gender_id,custom_108,custom_107,custom_109,custom_110" sequential=0}
{foreach from=$result.values item=contact}
  <tr><th>Date of Birth</th><th>Gender</th><th>Student Status</th> <th>Marital Status</th><th>Anniversary</th><th># of Children</th></tr>
  <tr><td>{$contact.birth_date}</td>
  <td>{$contact.gender_id}</td>
  <td>{$contact.custom_108}</td>
  <td>{$contact.custom_107}</td>
  <td>{$contact.custom_110}</td>
  <td>{$contact.custom_109}</td></tr>
{/foreach}
<tr><td><strong>Class Info</strong></td></tr>
{crmAPI var='result' entity='Contact' action='get' id=$contactId return="custom_118,custom_112,custom_113,custom_111"}
{foreach from=$result.values item=contact}
<tr><th>Class of</th><th>Campus</th><th>CG Leader</th> <th>Met Spouse at RI</th></tr>
  <tr><td>{$contact.custom_118}</td>
  <td>{$contact.custom_112}</td>
  <td>{$contact.custom_113}</td>
  <td>{$contact.custom_111}</td></tr>
{/foreach}
</table>
{/if}
{/foreach}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might just be a typo but you need `==` instead of `=`.

`{if $contact.contact_sub_type == 'Student'}`

But contact_sub_type is an array, so you could foreach over it and check if one of the values is Student.

Comment: Thanks! That was not a typo--just the scribbles of a bumbling idiot giving it a shot in the dark. I added the double == but it still does not work for any logins. If I remove the IF statement it does work but for all contact types.

Comment: Oh, it's because contact_sub_type is an array, so you could foreach thru it and check if one of the values is Student.

Comment: I am trying to just get to the contact_sub_type sub array, but not getting there. How do I get to the sub array?                                                                                              
 {crmAPI var='result' entity='Contact' action='get' id=$contactId sequential=0}
{foreach from=$result.values item=contact name=outer_loop}
  
    Name: {$contact.display_name}</br>
    Contact Type: {$contact.contact_type}</br>
    Sub Contact Type: {foreach from=$contact.contact_sub_type item=sub name=inner_loop}{$sub}, {foreachelse}<i>Nothing to see here</i>{/foreach}
{/foreach}

Comment: That looks ok. You can use `{debug}` after the crmAPI call to pop up a box that will show you what smarty thinks the variables are.

Comment: Thanks!!! Duh, the $ContactId I was testing on did not have a sub_type so of course it was not turning up any results. Once I saw the debug was empty I realized my error.

Comment: In case someone is looking for some code like this...{crmAPI var='result' entity='Contact' action='get' id=$contactId sequential=0}
{debug}
{foreach from=$result.values item=contact name=outer_loop}
  
    {foreach from=$contact.contact_sub_type item=sub name=inner_loop}
        {if $sub == 'Student'}
        
            {* Put in what you want to display for sub_types "Students" *}
        
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}